# My screen doesn't display anything, only the backlight works

Tags: laptop-repair, laptop-display, hp-laptop

I was wondering if anyone could help me out with this problem. I use an hp ProBook 4540s and I'm not quite sure why but whenever I restart the PC ( whether after a Windows update or perhaps after a hard reset) the display doesn't work. The backlight turns on but doesn't the screen doesn't show anything. I've tried a lot of things, taking out the battery (both the main and cmos batteries), reseating the memory module, connecting to an external display, reinstalling graphics drivers, reassembling the pc, and sending it to be repaired. Each of these has solutions has only been temporary. I was wondering if anyone had experienced this same problem, or  at least knew exactly what was going on and if there was one straight way to  fix it?  I can't afford another PC right now
Thanks in advance

PS. The whole warranty thing doesn't work in my part of the world so it's out of the options

Comment: Looks like you have a broken laptop display. Take it to a repair shop.

Comment: What do you mean by broken? I was using it about a few hours ago and had to restart after an update

Comment: I've also tried a different display, same thing.

Comment: If it's not working then it is broken ...

Comment: I think I should have pointed out that this is not the first time this has happened